# JPA 2.1 performant SaveAll in ManyToMany Relationship

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have the following entities Product(-placement) and CustomerReview with manyToMany relationship. I use Hibernate with spring-data-jpa to persist my entities.

```
public class ProductPlacement implements Serializable{

   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   public ProductPlacement(Long id){
       this.id = id;
   }

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
   @Column(name = "product_placement_id")
   private long id;

   @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="productPlacements")
   private Set<CustomerReview> customerReviews;
}

public class CustomerReview implements Serializable{

   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   @Id
   @Column(name = "customer_review_id")
   private String reviewIdentifier;

   @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   @JoinTable(
        name = "tb_miner_review_to_product",
           joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "customer_review_id"),
           inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "product_placement_id")
        )
   private Set<ProductPlacement> productPlacements;
}
```

Now I am looking for the most efficient way with the given technologies (Hibernate, spring-data-jpa, MySQL) to store a set of CustomerReviews for a ProductPlacement.

```
void saveAllReviews (List<CustomerReview> customerReviews, long productPlacementId);
```

The methode should add all new CustomerReviews where each Review references the productPlacement and should update the existing reviews (add new reference to productPlacement).

I could query the db for the ProductPlacement, than query the db for all reviews from the set. For all existing once I could add the Product as new reference, for all that do not exist I would create new Objects, but is this my only option? Or are their faster ways without querying the product and reviews first?
Thank you

**Update:** I get the reviews from an external service (via message queue). The message contains the information for which product it was scraped (productPlacementId) and the reviews in JSON format. Therefore i dont have the whole set of productPlacements the reviews belong to. The next message could contain a new productPlacement with the same reviews.

So for each message i need to look for each review, if the the review is already in the database (via primary key); if not -> I need to create a new Review Object and create a relationship to the productPlacement (which was in this message); if yes -> update the existing review (add a new relationship to the productPlacement in the message)

Comment: I think every `CustomerReview` and `ProductPlacement` knows each other by the relationship. So the set contains a set. Just put new ones in and update the ones you have. But maybe I dont understand the problem.

Comment: No, sry this was not clear from my question. The ProductPlacement is stored in the db, but in the set of customerReviews each review can be stored already or can be a new object.

Comment: ok. ProductPlacement has a set of CustomerReviews right? And you create new objects in this set? (From the DB there cannot come new objects). Now you have reviews which were already fetched and the new ones?

Comment: Updated my question. Maybe it's clearer now